# How to pass information between web forms in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

how to send some information from one web form to another web form in asp.net
first web form is `HumanList.aspx` that shows the list of humans in a `GridView` component.
when user click edit link, i want to pass humanID (value of human record ID) from `HumanList.aspx` to another web form named `HumanEdit.aspx`.
In humanEdit.aspx, i want to load that human (With `humanID`) and fill human information into text boxes.

Comment: Typically, queryString is use for this, not Session.

Answer (score 14):

There are many ways to pass params between pages.

1. Use `Querystring`.

Source page - `Response.Redirect("second.aspx?param=value");`

Destination page - `Request.QueryString["param"]`.

2. Use `Session`.

Source page - `Session["param"] = "value";` value is set here.

Destination page - `Session["param"].ToString()`. value is retrieved here.

3. Use `PreviousPage` property. Note: This applies if you redirect from `first.aspx` ( just an example here), to `second.aspx` , then you can use `PreviousPage.<propname>` in `second.aspx` to values set in `first.aspx`.

In `second.aspx` you need to add directive like this `<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/first.aspx" %>`.

4. Use `Request.Form` to read posted values.

If there are `input`, `dropdownlist` existing in source page and you are posting value to `second.aspx`, then you can read posted value using `Request.Form["input_id"]`.

5. Use `cookies` to transfer values. First save some value to cookie from `first.aspx` and read that value from `second.aspx`.

Refer to MSDN for more info - [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6c3yckfw(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using session or query string.

Session could be used like

pass value

```
 Session["value"]=someValue;
```

get value like

```
 var value= Session["value"].toString();
```

You could pass values with the help of properties too

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest storing it in the session state: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Answer (score -1):

**Well, there are many ways to pass information page to page.**

one primary way is by **QueryString**

```
//To Send
private void submit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string ID = String.Empty;

    ID = "192" // Have your ID Here

    Response.Redirect("humanEdit.aspx?ID=" + ID );
}


//To Receive
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   String ID = String.Empty;
   ID=Request.QueryString["name"];
}
```

Another Method is Sessions

```
//Store your ID from Sending Page
Session["ID"]= "143"; //Example ID

//To Recieve
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   String ID = String.Empty;
   ID=Session["ID"].toString();
}
```

And there are many other ways too...

Comment: Negative Voters can explain why this answer got down vote?

Comment: **ID=Request.QueryString["name"];** or **ID=Request.QueryString["ID"];** ?

Answer (score -2):

Say You have a gridview1 with a button field Say "Modify"
First Provide a command Name to that field Say "Mod"
Now in Gridview1_RowCommand() function of HumanList.aspx page write the code like this-

```
switch (e.CommandName.Trim())
{
case "Mod":
int r1=Int32.Parse((e.CommandArgument).ToString());
Session["id"]=GridView1.DataKeys[r1].Value.ToString();
Response.Redirect("HumanEdit.aspx?id=" + Session["id"]);
break;
}
```

Now in HumanEdit.aspx.cs you can make your own class and with in that class you can have a datatable object.Store the Sql query in that object and call that class in page_load().
Say class is

```
Public void show()
{
Within datatable object you can write your query like this
select x,y,z, from tbl_name where id=" + Request.QueryString["id"]
if(dt.Rows.Count>0)
{
Xtext.Text=dt.Rows[0]["x"].ToString();
Ytext.Text=dt.Rows[0]["y"].ToString();
Ztext.Text=dt.Rows[0]["z"].ToString();
}
}
```

This much of code is enough to get what you want.

Comment: @user3150674: Hello, If you feel like you have got help from the post, please mark it as answer. Thank You.
Feel free to ask your queries.