# Passing a Parameter When Clicking an ASP Literal

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, drop-down-menu, parameter-passing, href

I am working on an ASP.NET web forms project. I have two main web pages, `FirstPage` and `SecondPage`, each of which have a .aspx file and a .aspx.cs file. A drop down menu is on top of each page, and the values are taken from an Oracle database. Switching between the two pages is done by clicking on an asp literal. When `Firstpage.aspx` is loaded, user selects a value from the drop down list. The corresponding code in the .aspx file looks like this:

```
<a href="SecondPage.aspx">
    <asp:Literal runat="server" id="secondpagetab" EnableViewState="false"/>
</a>
```

What I need to do is to display that selected value as the default value of the drop down whenever the pages are switched. How do I do this? The value is loaded in the `FirstPage.aspx.cs` file. How can I pass it to the `SecondPage.aspx` file? Can I pass with the `href` tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass information between web forms in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866009/how-to-pass-information-between-web-forms-in-asp-net)

Comment: @dave Thank you very much. This helped.